# Binding data from main dom, to shadow doms in dom-repeat n Polymer

Tags: javascript, node.js, polymer-1.0

I am planning to use some grid details in shadow-dom.
Now I created a dom-repeat in the outer dom, which will create sub-doms [shadow-doms] for each row.
I am sending the data to show in Grid from the main-dom to shadow-dom as parameters.
Now when I make any changes in each sub-doms, I want that data to be reflected back to the main dom i.e if I trigger any event on main-dom, might be a button, I should get the updated data in the main-dom.

note: I am sending the data in dom-repeat to the shadow dom as {{item.element1}}, {{item.element2}}

Comment: It should be working out of the box what you want, but you need to add ```notify: true``` to your element property I think, but you can listen to the item ```property-name-changed``` event and synchronize the item into the dom-repeat datas.